# Initialize WordPress environment to use in a real cron script

Tags: php, cron, wp-cron, wp-load.php, command-line

I have to run a PHP script through real cron (WP cron being too unreliable). Within that script, I need $wpdb to insert data into WordPress table. But of course $wpdb will not be available as WordPress would not be initialized. Right? So, my question is how to 'include' WordPress/initialize WordPress environment to do such tasks? How about
    require_once("wp-load.php")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use real cron to trigger WP cron - by fetching `wp-cron.php` file from root ([snippet from quick google search](http://bitswapping.com/2010/10/using-cron-to-trigger-wp-cron-php/)).

That will take care of environment and everything.

Comment: Thanks! I hope this will also work when we have active cache plugins. Right? [See](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23665/scheduled-event-does-not-run-at-midnight/)

Comment: @Affan it completely should. The problem with caching plugins is triggering cron, WP cron file itself it not part of site's front-end and should not be affected by caching plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger any script via cron you can also skip wp-cron (limited functionality anyway) and cron the script directly.

The script have to load the wordpress environment itself if it wants to use wordpress functionality.

A solution to this can be found here : [Initialize WordPress environment to use in command line script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76465/initialize-wordpress-environment-to-use-in-command-line-script/76466#76466)