# Cron job script - loading wordpress system fails

Tags: cron, wp-load.php

I want to run a cron job that fetches data from an api and stores it in a database table.

I don't use "wp-cron". I load a script in a folder inside the theme. But I need to load the wordpress system somehow, so I have this code inside the script:

```
require_once( '../../../../../wp-load.php' );
```

I was thinking that I could require the wordpress system by requiring "`wp-load.php`", (which is also done in "wp-cron.php")  and after that I could import my custom classes which make use of `$wpdb` and other wordpress stuff.

If I only run a simple database insert and nothing else (with normal mysql syntax), it works. But when adding the require statement , it fails. Do you know why?
And do you know how I could make this work, so I can make use of the wordpress system?

**EDIT**
The problem is with "require_once", so it's not wordpress related... If I try to require another script, and put my test database insert code there, that script never runs.

So in the main script I do:

```
require_once( 'hello.php' );
```

In "hello.php" I have the database insert (which works if I put it in the original file, without no require statements.

I use windows task scheduler to run the script, so maybe it's more related to that.

**EDIT2:**

I tried placing the script in the root folder, so the require became:

```
require_once( 'wp-load.php' );
```

and this time it worked! So the problem seems to be related to using paths going back to the parents ( `../../../etc` ) . I also tried absolute paths but wasn't lucky.

Comment: Have you checked that `../../../../../wp-load.php` is actually pointing to wp-load.php? If the script is in a directory directly under your theme root, you have one too many `../`. You should also activate WP_DEBUG to give you some info on why it is crashing.

Comment: Yes if I try to require a different file in the main directory and just echo something, and load the script in the browser, it is required correctly, so that path is working. I also tried to require wp-load , which worked when loading it in the browser. But I'm using windows task scheduler for the cron, and I can't see any errors.

Comment: related questions and possible answers [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23990/initialize-wordpress-environment-to-use-in-a-real-cron-script) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76465/initialize-wordpress-environment-to-use-in-command-line-script/76466)